# IBM Bluemix Message Hub Producer Message Format

Tags: apache-kafka, ibm-cloud, message-hub

The "Getting started with Message Hub (BETA)" page on bluemix.net indicates that for a Java producer "...the message must be in the following form: [{ "value" : string }, ...] ".

I cannot find any reference in the Kafka documentation to this format, the service works perfectly fine when text is sent that is not in that format, and when I tried using it, the consumer did not separate multiple "value" strings -- the multiple values just arrived as a single JSON message.

So does anyone have some thoughts on the origin, need, or potential benefit of this stated requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, this statement isn't correct. Thanks for querying this. The Message Hub docs are currently undergoing a review and we're working on getting an updated version available as soon as possible.